# Problem assigning integer a value from an array index

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to create a function that takes a string as an input and extracts the first digit as an output. Here is the relevant code. I am new to coding so tips are appreciated.

```
int extractNum(string id){
    int num=0;
    bool found=false;

    for(int i=0; i<id.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(id[i])){
            num=id[i];
            found=true;
            if(found=true){
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
    return num;
};
```

The problem I am facing is when ever I pass a example string like "vr2498" it does take the '2' but on assigning the value to a variable or returning the value it changes to 50. Which is incorrect.

Summary: Need to extract first digit from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your restult `num` is an integer, but the "2" in your string is a character. When you assign `num=id[i]`, you're converting the character "2" to its ASCII value, which is 50.

So, you need to convert that. The simplest way would be to just do `num = id[i] - '0'`. That works because in ASCII, numbers are consecutive with "0" being the first one.

The better solution here would be to use something like [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which does that conversion. This would also allow converting more than one digit if that's what you want.

Also note you can just return from the loop directly, no need for `break` and `found`.

```
int extractNum(string id){
   for(int i=0; i<id.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(id[i])){
            //here, you could take more than one character
            const auto digitString = id.substr(i, 1);
            return std::stoi(digitString);               
        }  
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: It's better to subtract `'0'` as this works even in non-ASCII character sets (standard requires the digits 0-9 to follow one another immediately – if that's not the case for a character set then it is not compatible to neither C++ nor C).

Comment: @Yunnosch it seems I really can't read today

Comment: @perivesta That comment changed my perception of you completly. Before that I thought the same and was not impressed. With that comment I admire your professional ability to take feedback and see your own (if harmless) shortcomings. Cool.

Comment: Just a side note: My personal preference would rather have been `char*` based `strtol` to avoid *copying* the substring: `return strtol(id.c_str() + i, nullptr, 10);` – actually even `strtoul` (with adopted return type) as we don't scan for `'-'` either and thus negative results won't occur anyway...

Comment: Good point, I forgot `strtol` takes an end pointer, unlike `atoi`. In that case yes, that's probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
int extractNum(string id){
    int num=0;
    bool found=false;

    for(int i=0; i<id.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(id[i])){
            num=id[i];
            found=true;
            if(found=true){
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
    return num-'0';
}
```

The value you are getting is the ASCII value of 2 as '2' is still a character for the compiler and is integral value is 50
Just subtract the required character with character '0' to get the actual integral value

Comment: You took over the weird `found=true;
            if(found=true){break;}` where `break;` would do the same. Do you have special reasons for that?

Comment: no, I was confused at the output tried implementing different stuff to fix it. I added those because somehow I thought the loop was affecting the outcome.

Comment: I now understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ASCII value of `'2'`, it is 50.
You can subtract `'0'`, to get a value 2.
This is assuming you want some hands-on.
There are functions to do this for you.